# Get the first element of System.array?

Tags: c#

I am writing a script for a task in `DisplayFusion`. There's an array with window classes of which I need the first.

How to get the first element of `System.array` **regardless of the index' type**?

I tried

```
String windowClass = BFS.Window.GetClass(myArray[Array.IndexOf(myArray)]);
```

but that throws an error

> (No overloading for method 'IndexOf', accepts 1-Arguments)

Comment: `myArray[0]` would get you the first element. Not sure what you're trying to achieve with IndexOf here, but the error is because IndexOf needs (at least) **two** input values - the array you want to search, and the value to search for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8 . The purpose of IndexOf is to find the first occurrence of a specific value inside the array - it will then tell you at which array index that occurs. In your code, you haven't provided a specific value to search for.

Comment: The answer is in the error message: there are no overloads of [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof) that accept a single parameter; you need to tell it the index _of what_ (to find).  Consequentially, `IndexOf` is not for retrieving an element given an index, it's for finding an index for a given element.

Comment: How to get the first index then?

Comment: the first index is always 0. Therefore `myArray[0]` will return the first element in the array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: Usually when programmers write Array class code they are dealing with interop.  COM libraries in particular do not always create arrays whose first index is 0, Basic programmers expect to start at 1.  Use Array.GetLowerBound().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOf` is for finding the index of the first element in the array that matches the value you passed. I think you're after `[0]`.

```
String windowClass = BFS.Window.GetClass(myArray[0]);
```

Please note that if the array is empty this will throw an exception.

You could also use `.First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` from `System.Linq`, but `[0]` is made for what you need.